# Bayesian Bandits - What's the probability that choice K is the best?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, integration

I have $K$ very unfair coins. I don't know how unfair they are, but they all seem to have different probabilities of landing heads. I'd like to figure out which one is best as quickly as possible.

Being mathematically inclined, I flipped each one a handful of times and measured my success. Based on the results, I've constructed a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)
for each coin.

Given the beta distributions I have, what is the probability that coin i is the most likely of all coins to flip heads? That is, the true success rate of coin $i$ is some $X_i$, and I want to know the probability that $X_i \geq X_j$ for all $j$ given what I know so far.

I'm sure I could do some Monte Carlo simulations and get a good estimate, but I suspect there's some kind of direct answer involving nested integrals- like doing an infinite number of Monte Carlo simulations.

Deeper reasoning: I want to implement a [Multi-armed bandit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) solution to a problem, but I'd like to randomly select from my options weighing on how likely it is this one is the best. My plan right now is to use Monte-Carlo, but the more accurate I want those ratios to be, the more CPU cycles I'm burning and the less often I want to update my ratios.

But seeing as I only managed a minor in math (nearly a decade ago) I know I am in way over my head trying to analyze this problem. Any ideas?

**Edit later for further clarity and simplicity:**

Given two Beta distributions $Beta(α1,β1)$ and $Beta(α2,β2)$ estimating some variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, what is $P(X_1 >= X_2)$? Can this be calculated directly without just generating random values from each distribution over and over and estimating?

Comment: This seems to be an ill-constructed question; in order to have probabilities relating the biases of the coins, you need the biases themselves to have a random distribution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965376/maximum-of-beta-distributed-random-variables/2965587

Comment: Isn't this exactly what Thompson's sampling is doing? It draws one sampling from each distribution and picks the best one.

Comment: @RHahn - Yes, I think that is asking a similar question. I don't think the answers there quite suffice though. The question is: given the beta distributions I have that are estimating each X, how likely is it that X_i is the greatest?

Comment: @N.Gast: Yes, it is. But I don't want to randomly sample (the Monte Carlo solution), I want to analytically answer the question "What is the probability that X_i is the max".